# php mysql "like button" notification

Tags: php, mysql

What's the shortest way to write a php/mysql code that groups all "likes" related to a certain post, and even shows the people who clicked the like button as in the following example:

John, Mary, Brian and others liked this comment

Comment: `SELECT * FROM likes WHERE postId=?` ?

Comment: Suppose you have 20 "like buttons" on a single page, for different pieces of information. 
And each button is clicked by a 1000 people.

Doesnt "SELECT * FROM likes WHERE postId=?" become a bit slow and inneficient?

Comment: It would become very slow, but you asked for the shortest way.

Comment: @Boann You are right, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not give any other details other than what you want, this is all based on an assumption of how your DB might be set up.

SQL query:

```
 SELECT * FROM likes WHERE (comment or post id) = 'ID'
```

post_id is the thing you want to group by, so for instance, if each comment has it's own ID, then you want to group your likes by that.

My DB I have that does likes is set up like this:

Fields: id, comment_id, post_id, name

So you would have it like:

```
+--------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+
|    ID        |   comment_id  |    post_id   |   name       |
+--------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+
|     1        |     382       |     null     |   John       |
|     2        |     382       |     null     |   Mary       |
|     3        |     null      |     189      |   Brian      |
|     4        |     null      |     189      |   Joe        |
|     5        |     382       |     null     |   Ryan       |
|     6        |     382       |     null     |   Bell       |
+--------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+
```

So if you use the SQL script:

```
SElECT * FROM likes WHERE comment_id = '382'
```

You will get the following:

```
+--------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+
|    ID        |   comment_id  |    post_id   |   name       |
+--------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+
|     1        |     382       |     null     |   John       |
|     2        |     382       |     null     |   Mary       |
|     5        |     382       |     null     |   Ryan       |
|     6        |     382       |     null     |   Bell       |
+--------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Then you would run a script (assuming it is PHP) like this:

```
$num = 0; // This is used as an identifier
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($getdata); // Count the number of likes on your comment or post

if($numrows > 3) { 
    $ending = 'and others like this comment.'; // If there are more than 3 likes, it ends this way
} else { 
    $ending = 'like this comment.'; // If there are less than or equal to 3 likes, it will end this way
}

while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($getdata)) {
    if($num => 3) { // This says that if the $num is less than or equal to 3, do the following
        // This will be used to list the first 3 names from your database and put them in a string like: name1, name2, name3, 
        $names = $data['name'].', ';
        // This adds a number to the $num variable.
        $num++;
    }
}

echo $names.' '.$ending; //Finally, echo the result, in this case, it will be: John, Mary, Ryan, and other like this comment.
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks Brian!
You literally read my mind! This is exactly what I need!
Let me test the code and get back to you!